# animating opacity text css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some text, it is one word (countinue) and i want to create that word will be black and after 31second it will be orange. I tried a lot of combinations with css but i can't create that effect. Here is my try :

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hD77v/)

This is great but i don't know how to stop it.. i need only one time to show that text. It would be great if it is possible to opacity be 0 and after 31seconds opacity will be 1.

```
div
{
width:25px;
height:25px;
background:red;
position:relative;
animation:mymove 5s infinite;
animation-delay:2s;

/*Safari and Chrome*/
-webkit-animation:mymove 5s infinite;
-webkit-animation-delay:2s;
}

@keyframes mymove
{
from {left:0px;}
to {left:200px;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes mymove /*Safari and Chrome*/
{
from {left:0px;}
to {left:200px;}
}
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Comment: I don't get it, there's no opacity styles in you sample code.

Comment: You want to change the color of text after 31 seconds?
and animation only once?

Comment: well yes. My background is black and text should be black to, and after 31second it must be orange. :) just like text appear effect.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sE8FN/ like this?

Answer (score 1):

For stopping animation you can use

```
animation-iteration-count: 1;
```

JSfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hD77v/1/

for changing background-color after 31 seconds
HTML

```
<div id="test">continue</div>
```

CSS

```
#test {
background-color : red;
}
```

Javascript

```
setTimeout(function(){
document.getElementById("test").style.backgroundColor="black";
},31000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want this:

```
from{left:0px;opacity:0;}
to{left:200px;opacity:1;}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/C8d6H/